# SQL sum by month with the previous values

Tags: sql, count, sum, mysql-5.1

I have following data:

```
  cohort   activity  counter
 -----------------------------
  2010-12    0         470
  2010-12    1          2
  2010-12    2          1
  2010-12    3          1
  2010-12    6          1
  2011-01    0         550
  2011-01    1          1
  2011-01    6          1
```

I want to sum counter of different activities by month, so the final table looks like:

```
  cohort   activity  counter   sumResult
 -------------------------------------------
  2010-12     0         470     470
  2010-12     1          2      472
  2010-12     2          1      473
  2010-12     3          1      474
  2010-12     6          1      475
  2011-01     0         550     550
  2011-01     1          1      551
  2011-01     6          1      552
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
select
a.activity, a.counter, a.cohort,
(
select sum(b.counter)
from data_table as b
where b.cohort = a.cohort and b.counter >= a.counter
) as sumResult
from data_table as a;
GO;
```

but it gave me strange results as:

```
 cohort   activity  counter   sumResult
 -------------------------------------------
  2010-12     0         470     470
  2010-12     1          2      472
  2010-12     2          1      475
  2010-12     3          1      475
  2010-12     6          1      475
  2011-01     0         550     550
  2011-01     1          1      552
  2011-01     6          1      552
```

What could be a problem?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this uses the ANSI standard cumulative sum function:

```
select dt.*,
       sum(dt.counter) over (partition by dt.cohort order by dt.counter desc)
from data_table dt
order by cohort, counter desc;
```

If you want to use a subquery, the you need a stable sort, and `activity` can give you one.  You can use this in the cumulative sum syntax:

```
select dt.*,
       sum(dt.counter) over (partition by dt.cohort order by dt.counter desc, dt.activity)
from data_table dt
order by cohort, counter desc, activity;
```

Or using a subquery:

```
select dt.*,
       (select sum(dt2.counter)
        from data_table dt2
        where dt2.cohort = dt.cohort and
              (dt2.counter > dt.counter or
               dt2.counter = dt.counter and dt2.activity < dt.activity)
       )
from data_table dt
order by cohort, counter desc, activity;
```

Comment: I think it should be `ORDER BY dt.activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your RDBMS , some(SQL Server,Oracle,Postgresql) of them will accept `SUM() OVER()` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(t.counter) OVER(PARTITION BY t.cohort ORDER BY t.activity) as sumResult
FROM YourTable t
```

If it's another, that's a bit more complicated and can be dealt with `JOINS`